# What is the "DNS timeout value" relevant to a Salesforce Site Switching?

Tags: site.com, enterprise, ip-whitelisting

We are about to undergo Salesforce Site Switching and the notification cautions that we should set our "DNS timeout value to 5 minutes (default setting)"  [See point #4 here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Site-Switching-Overview&language=en_US&type=1 ]

I would like to confirm this setting, but I'm not certain what they mean.  Is this a setting internal to Salesforce or are they referring to TTL on some external DNS provider (but then what would they mean by default setting of 5 minutes)?

I'd be most grateful to anyone who could clarify the meaning and point us to the right place.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are indeed referring to DNS server resource records with a Time To Live (TTL) value of 300 seconds.

Salesforce sets the TTL for 300 seconds (5 minutes) on the resource records that they are the authority on and the recommendation is that an upstream caching server (for instance, one within your enterprise infrastructure) should also use this value and not cache these records for more than 300 seconds. 86400 seconds (24 hours) was common in the past.

In short, don't keep these records longer than 300 seconds and your users are not likely to notice the site switch.

Comment: Thanks, Mark.  That's exactly the clarification I was looking for.  Most grateful.  By the way it was worded, I wasn't sure if there was perhaps some DNS TTL setting within the Salesforce interface that might have been changed at some point from a default of 5 minutes.